# Simultaneous imputation of multiple binary variables in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a dataset with multiple correlated binary variables (0/1). Can anyone point me towards a solution how to impute completely random missing values based on information in the other variables?

Below, I provide some code to create a simplified dataset with just 3 correlated binary variables.

```
# create correlated random binary (0/1) variables
x1 <- runif(100,0,1)          # N(0,1))
x2 <- x1 * runif(100,0,1)     # N(0,1))
x3 <- x2 * runif(100,0,1)+0.2 # N(0,1))
x1 <- round(x1)
x2 <- round(x2)
x3 <- round(x3)

#introduce random missing (MCAR)
x1[seq(1,100,7)]<-NA
x2[seq(2,100,7)]<-NA
x3[seq(3,100,7)]<-NA

# how can I impute missing values in this dataframe?
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3))
cor(df,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Thanks so much,

Micha

Comment: Try [Amelia](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [mice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) package.

```
> library(mice)
Loading required package: Rcpp
mice 2.21 2014-02-05
> df.imputed <- complete(mice(df))
# mice output deleted
> nrow(df) == sum(complete.cases(df.imputed))
[1] TRUE
> cor(df.imputed)
          x1        x2        x3
x1 1.0000000 0.4645345 0.2914986
x2 0.4645345 1.0000000 0.6787420
x3 0.2914986 0.6787420 1.0000000
```